# Why do I receive urlopen no attribute error in python 3.7.3?

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen, simplejson

Im new to python and trying to work on geocode data.

I have written the below code to find the drive time between to geocodes.

```
import urllib.request
#from urllib.request import urlopen
import simplejson, urllib
orig_lat = 52.2296756
orig_lng = 21.0122287
dest_lat = 52.406374
dest_lng = 16.9251681
orig_coord = orig_lat, orig_lng
dest_coord = dest_lat, dest_lng
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false".format(str(orig_coord),str(dest_coord))
result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
driving_time = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']
```

However, I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-154-c5d2043b6825>", line 11, in <module>
    result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))

AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

I have seen other posts about this, but none of them work for me as a solution to this attribute error.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Which other posts did you consult?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Python 3, `urllib.urlopen` has been [replaced](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) with `urllib.request.urlopen()`. Change `urllib.urlopen(url)` to `urllib.request.urlopen(url)`.

See the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) for more information.

Comment: its python 3.7.3

Comment: Then use the method I suggested